# Why is OnValue from firebase not firing here?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I followed all the installations from the `expo` regarding firebase, for web and android. When I run the app the on web I get the data fine, however, when I run it on android the `onValue` method does not run.

It doesn't give any errors either.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import {useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getDatabase, onValue, ref } from 'firebase/database';
import { fb } from '../firebaseConfig'
import { LogBox } from 'react-native';
const db = getDatabase();
LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Setting a timer']);

const HomePage = ({navigation})=>{


 const [count, setCount] = useState([]);
 useEffect(() => {
  const cart = ref(db,"cart/");
  onValue(cart,(snapshot)=>{
      const data = snapshot.val();
      console.log(data)
      setCount(data)
}) },[]);

const sendData = (name, surname) =>{
     navigation.navigate('Map', { name: name, surname: surname} )
}



    return(
       <View>
           <FlatList data = {Object.keys(count)}
            renderItem={({item})=> 
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {sendData(count[item].name, count[item].Surname)}}>
            <Text>{count[item].name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
             />
       </View>
)

}

export default HomePage
```

this is my `app.json`

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-app",
    "slug": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.mypackage.myapp",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are **not** passing an error callback as third argument to `onValue()` it may just look like the function is not firing when it actually executed but then failed and got canceled.

The failure may be due to a permission error, therefore make sure to add an `cancelCallback` function.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#onvalue):

> An optional callback that will be notified **if your event subscription is ever canceled because your client does not have permission to read this data** (or it had permission but has now lost it). This callback will be passed an Error object indicating why the failure occurred.

```
export declare function onValue(
  query: Query,
  callback: (snapshot: DataSnapshot) => unknown,
  cancelCallback?: (error: Error) => unknown // <--- error handler
): Unsubscribe;
```